# How to bind form input value in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want the value of `total` box equivalent to the product of `price` and `quantity`. Without reactive form it was quite easy by using banana in box syntax. How do I achieve the same in reactive-forms

here is my form code

```
addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      deposit: ['', Validators.required],
      total: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

and here is the html of `total` input

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">

    <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
        <input type='number' value='deposit*quantity' formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Total" required>

</mat-form-field>
```

image of my form
[image: form image]

Comment: Should the Total field really be a field in the Form rather then just a a text output for deposit * quantity? (i guess you should not be able to change it?) -> you could create a getter for this value in your component getTotal(FormGroup) => total

Answer (score 3):

```
value='33' // dont do that


addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: ['', Validators.required],
      deposit: ['', Validators.required],
      total: ['33', Validators.required], // do that!
    });
  }
```

---

Edited:

Based on your response, I'd say remove `total` from the formGroup since it is not actually a user input. Rather do something liek this:

```
total$: Observable<number>;

this.total$ = this.productFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(formValue => +formValue.quantity * +formValue.price)
)

<div>Total: {{ total$ | async }}</div>
```

Comment: I've edited the question, please check now
I want the total to be the product of `price` and  `quantity`

Comment: I don't think this will work in my case, because when I will add a new row (please see the attached image to have a better idea) the total will same for all rows.
How to deal with this situation. Please 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, that's can not work. If you use `|async` you only get the value in a first time -async unsubcribe the observable-

Comment: @Eliseo that is not true. The async pipe also refreshes the value. It's not once

Comment: You're rigth, sorry my confussion

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this works out ([Link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8t3qpo))

```
ngOnInit(){

this.formGroup =  this.fb.group({
  quantity : [0 ,[]],
  value:[0,[]],
  total:[0]
})

this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(this.isSame)
).subscribe(values =>{
  console.log(values)
  const {value, quantity} = values;
  this.formGroup.patchValue(
    {
      total : value * quantity
    }
  )
})}

isSame(prev, next) {
  return (prev.value === next.value)
 && (prev.quantity === next.quantity);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8t3qpo?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: looks pretty good, I just saw the stackBlitz example, but its not working in my example

Comment: because I've dynamic number of rows, (see the image to get the better idea) i.e. when user will add a new row, will not be the total same in all rows ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do something like

```
public get total(): any {
   if (this.form.get('price').value && this.form.get('quantity').value) {
       return this.form.get('price').value * this.form.get('quantity').value;
   }
   return '';
}
```

**Note :** You need to create form and need to store formGroup return value in that

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to value changes similar to the following:

```
    // build formgroup then ...

    // calculate total
    this.formGroup.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(20), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.calculateLineItemTotal();
      });
```

```
  private calculateLineItemTotal(): number {
    // get quantity and rate values
    const quantity = +this.formGroup.controls.LineQuantity.value;
    const rate = +this.formGroup.controls.LineRate.value;

    // verify if blank
    if (!quantity || !rate) {
      this.formGroup.controls.LineTotal.setValue("", {
        emitEvent: false
      });
      return 0;
    }

    this.formGroup.controls.LineTotal.setValue((quantity * rate).toFixed(2), {
      emitEvent: false
    });
    return quantity * rate;
  }
```

Warning - This gets ugly fast (think patching value when in edit mode) so best avoided if possible as alluded to be Jenson in the comments.